# How to have the option of using sys.arg or raw_input as ways of importing files on python?

Tags: python

Currently I have a short program which can take two different files on the command line as so: $python myscript.py file1 file2
This is through using the sys.arg function, as in:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as a, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as b:
while True:
    try:
        #code does stuff for file1
while True:
     try:
        #code does stuff for file2
```

The other way of importing the files is by asking the user to input the file names as so:

```
while True:
    userin = raw_input("Options (1, 2 or 3): ")
    if userin == '1':
        fileopen = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
        #etc etc
```

However, I would like to combine these- so that I can either specify the two files on the command line along with the program- or just open the program and then specify the files. How might I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Use an if statement. `if len(argv) >= 3: Do cmd line \ else: Do input`

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use an if-statement. For example:

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    filename1 = sys.argv[1]
    filename2 = sys.argv[2]
else:
    filename1 = raw_input("Enter filename 1")
    filename2 = raw_input("Enter filename 2")
```

Or, if you don't want to write code twice:

```
def getFilename(position):
    if position < len(sys.argv): # Filename not given as argument
        return sys.argv[position]
    else:
        return raw_input("Enter filename of file number {}".format(position))


filename1 = getFilename(1)
filename2 = getFilename(2)
```

However, if you plan on adding more command line arguments in the future, using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) would probably be a good idea.